# How to render HTML with image tag using phpword?

Tags: php, html, doc, phpword

```
<?php

$html = <p>test</p><img src="https://www.xub.edu.in/images/xavier-logo1.png" width="100%" class="desktopLogo" alt="" title="">

$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

When writing it to docs with the `img` tag, a blank doc gets downloaded. How can I render html with image tag using phpword properly?

Answer (score -2):

You should close the img tag with / first and put whole image url to the link

like this:

```
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-giant-flamingo-and-watermelon-pool-float-in-swimming-pool-753390586.jpg" />
```

in my case it worked.